# Select dummy data for a certain period of years based on some conditions from a main query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

The following query returns all ExceptionDays of an employee:

```
SELECT
     idEmployee, idExceptionDayType,
     YEAR(startDate) year,
     SUM (days) total
 FROM
     ExceptionDays ed
GROUP BY idEmployee, idExceptionDayType, YEAR(startDate)
```

I need to generate dummy ExceptionDays starting with the hiring year of the employee till current year. This subquery shouldn't create dummy data if a year already exists in the ExceptionDays table for the current employee.

So basically, if the employee was hired in 2010 and it has data in ExceptionDays table only for 2014 and 2015 , the query should return 2010,2011,2012,2013 as dummy data and for 2014 and 2015 it should get the valid data.

For generating dummy data I used a temporary calendar of years :

```
 SELECT 
    1 as idEmployee,1 as idExceptionDayType,YEAR(c.date) year,0 total
   FROM 
     TMP_CALENDAR c WITH (NOLOCK)
  WHERE
     YEAR(c.date) >= 2012
 AND YEAR(c.date) < YEAR(GETDATE())
GROUP BY YEAR(c.date)
```

This second subquery should somehow be joined to the first query and the expecting query would become :

```
   SELECT 
         ED.idEmployee,1 as idExceptionDayType,YEAR(c.date) year,0 total
       FROM 
         TMP_CALENDAR c WITH (NOLOCK)
         JOIN Employees E ON ED.idEmployee = E.idEmployee
      WHERE
         YEAR(c.date) >= YEAR(e.hiringDate)
     AND YEAR(c.date) < YEAR(GETDATE()) AND YEAR <> YEAR(ed.year)
    GROUP BY YEAR(c.date)
```

As we can see the ED reference to the first query is needed so the query would become valid but I'm not sure how I'm supposed to do that.

Can someone help me a lil bit?
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind this type of query is to generate the output rows first -- using a `CROSS JOIN` to get all the years and employees, and then additional logic to bring in the other values.

The following version just uses `ExceptionDays` to get all the years, assuming there is at least one such day in each year.  You can also use a calendar table for the `y` subquery:

```
SELECT e.idEmployee, COALESCE(ed.idExceptionDayType, 1) as idExceptionDayType
      y.year, COALESCE(SUM(ed.days), 0) as total
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT idEmployee FROM ExceptionDays) e CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(startDate) as year FROM ExceptionDays) y LEFT JOIN
     ExceptionDays ed
     ON ed.idEmployee = e.idEmployee and
        y.year BETWEEN YEAR(ed.startDate) AND year(GETDATE())
GROUP BY e.idEmployee, ed.idExceptionDayType, y.year
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

1. Get all distinct Years from Calendar
2. Cross Join with all Employees and filter to get only those years after employee has joined
3. Filter only those employees which do not have an entry in ExceptionDays for the specific year

**Query**

```
   SELECT 
         E.idEmployee,1 as idExceptionDayType,calendar_year,0 total
       FROM 
         (
            SELECT YEAR(c.date) calendar_year
            FROM TMP_CALENDAR
            GROUP BY YEAR(c.date)
         )c
         CROSS JOIN Employees E
         LEFT JOIN ExceptionDays ed
         ON ED.idEmployee = E.idEmployee
         AND ed.YEAR(startDate) = calendar_year
      WHERE calendar_year >= YEAR(e.hiringDate)
        AND calendar_year < YEAR(GETDATE())
        AND ED.idEmployee IS NULL
```